# TCP response with RST, ACK

Tags: tcp, packet-capture

My unit is supposed to send CSR request to a CA server and get the new certificate. When checked packets captured via Wireshark, TCP packet is sent with SYN but received RST,ACK. When tried to identify the root cause for this, I see many possibilities in the web. Now, how how to identify the actual reason for this failure?